# Unable to authenticate using adfs as the federated authenticator in wso2 with travelocity app

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0, federated-identity, wso2-identity-server

When i have a single adfs configured as a identity server on wso2, authentication from wso2 fails with the below error.

> ator returned: INCOMPLETE TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-24 06:50:04,580]
>   DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler}
>   -  SAMLSSOAuthenticator is redirecting TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-24 06:50:04,580] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler}
>   -  Step is not complete yet. Redirechttp://stackoverflow.com/questionsting to outside. TID: [-1234]
>   [] [2017-02-24 06:50:09,958] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.util.FrameworkUtils}
>   -  Authentication Context is null TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-24 06:50:09,959] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
>   -  Session data key is null in the request TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-24 06:50:09,959] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
>   -  Context does not exist. Probably due to invalidated cache

At the same time if there are more than one federated authentication say 2 adfs servers configured on wso2 as identity server and using the advanced configuration option on wso2-sp , authentication from travelocity is happening fine.

please guide what am i missing here.

Comment: can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

This is supported out-of-the-box with Identity Server 5.1.0 M3 onwards. If you are to use this with Identity Server 5.0.0 (with SP 1) you’ll need to some modifications to the source. The details can be found at [1] & [2].

Follow Document[3] for more details for Setting ADFS 3.0 as a Federated Authenticator in WSO2 Identity Server

[1] - https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-3181
[2] - https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-3349
[3] - https://omindu.wordpress.com/2015/06/19/setting-ad-fs-3-0-as-federated-authenticator-in-wso2-identity-server/

Comment: we followed the exact steps as mentioned in the link https://omindu.wordpress.com/2015/06/19/setting-ad-fs-3-0-as-federated-authenticator-in-wso2-identity-server/ but still we have the same error when using single adfs as federated authenticator in wso2 - SP configuration.

we use the saml php app for testing the sso and our wso2 - is version is 5.3